# Problems with `conn <- dbConnect()` but a clean `dbConnect()` is executing

Tags: r, odbc, dbi

I have a Shiny app up and running for over 250 days without any issues but suddenly I've got some issues with the connection to the database. While trying to debug in the Rstudio IDE (in another docker container on the same server) I get the same db connection problems.

The odd thing is shown in the screenshot below. When connecting without storing the connection into a variable it is executing, but when I try to store it in a the variable `conn` with `conn <- DBI::dbConnect(...)` it is not responding. Obvious, the in the `Shiny` app this is used a lot. Thus the connection seems to be working but... not really.

Does anybody have any experience with this type of issues and can enlighten me about the possible root causes of what is happening? I appreciate your insights.

Unfortunately, I cannot share any reproducible code for this issue as it is specific to the environment it is running.

[image]

Comment: I cannot think of any reason why *assignment* would change the behavior of `dbConnect`. I can believe, however, that you are hitting a usage-cap: the first two connections *are still being used* (according to the DBMS), so when you assign to `conn`, the DBMS sees two already-connected and a third new connection. Eventually, R will garbage-collect the first two (and the DBMS at that time seeing them closed). Check to see if you have a limit on simo connections. Or better yet, just assign it the first time. (You might need to restart R to force everything closed.)

Comment: @r2evans: thanks for the your answer. I just restarted the docker container including R and it still doesn't let me assign. As the R session is hanging, I cannot check without assigning. The odd thing is that this has been running for months in a production environment. I will check if there are any limits on simo connections on the DB end. Thanks for the help.